# How to fix Windows 10 Command Prompt from waiting for input

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

When I run something in command prompt (For exmaple: **npm**), from time to time in title I can see `Select *title*` insted of `*title*`. If is appears cmd is wait when I focus on it and click something. After that command is continue executing.

Also if I click somewhere in the command prompt whlie something is executing, the problem repeats.

*So, how can I remove this some kind of pause from cmd?*

Comment: You need to supply info about the `.bat` script and where the error occurs.

Comment: No, because it is in every script i run

Comment: @harrymc This is [Code](http://bit.ly/2SALkrW) and [Result](https://streamable.com/agavq)
  
In result I run script but nothing happens. Then I click on the window, then title changes to `Select C:\Users\...`, but still nothing happens. Then I click `Enter`, and command continue executing

Comment: @harrymc no need. Naziks is experiencing a simple behavior of CMD, nothing that is a problem with any script. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening, is because you entered select mode.

When you click anywhere inside the window of a commandprompt (and not the titlebar) you start to make a selection. a white square will appear indicating your selection.

To cancel, right-click, which means: copy the selection to clipboard, and resume.

You can disable this functionality as follows:

On the command prompt window, click on the icon in the top left of the window (left of the title) to open the menu, and select Properties.

Go to the options tab, and disable Quick Edit Mode (first checkbox).

Hit ok and clicking will no longer make a selection, neither as dragging.

To make a selection now, right-click the window and select: 'select' to enter selection mode.

Quick edit mode is enabled by default in windows 10 from a certain build. I forgot which one though...